# How to pass multiple arguments within subprocess.check_call()?

Tags: python, bash, arguments

How can I pass multiple arguments within my subprocess call in python while running my shell script?

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('./test_bash.sh '+arg1 +arg2, shell=True)
```

This prints out the arg1 and arg2 concatenated as one argument. I would need to pass 3 arguments to my shell script.

Comment: can you try `check_call(['./test_bash.sh',arg1,arg2],shell=True)` ? or drop shell=True and add `["sh","-c",` before your bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course it concatenates because you're not inserting a space between them. Quickfix would be (with `format`, and can fail if some arguments contain spaces)

```
 subprocess.check_call('./test_bash.sh {} {}'.format(arg1,arg2), shell=True)
```

can you try (more robust, no need to quote spaces, automatic command line generation):

```
check_call(['./test_bash.sh',arg1,arg2],shell=True)`
```

(not sure it works on all systems because of `shell=True` and argument list used together)

or drop `shell=True` and call the shell explicitly (may fail because *shebang* is not considered, unlike with `shell=True`, but it's worth giving up `shell=True`, liable to code injection among other issues):

```
check_call(['sh','-c','./test_bash.sh',arg1,arg2])
```

Comment: awesome, that did it.

Comment: how can I pass the same multiple arguments that are stored as a list such as arg1={}, arg2={} and I'd like the script to use arg1[0], arg2[0] first and then increment to next arg1[1], arg2[1].

Comment: just create a list that you'll add to the "first arguments" list. but you'll need to zip & flatten: `["sh','-c","test_bash_whatever] + list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(arg1,arg2)))` something like that